# Adding items into QcomboBox without changing the current selected item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to add items into comboBox object but the current item will change into the newly added item.

Example:

```
#comboBox have initial item "initial item"
comboBox.addItem("new added item1")
comboBox.addItem("new added item2")
```

Now the example above will change the current item into `"new added item2"`. Is there a way to retain the current text to `"initial item"` while adding new items?

Comment: I did not observe that problem, could provide a [mre] in addition to pointing out the characteristics of your environment: OS, python and pyqt5 version

Comment: Hello, i now know the problem and its that if i set the index into ```-1``` and call ```comboBox.clear()``` and ```comboBox.addItem("dummy")``` it resets the index and set it to 0 which points to the newly added item.

Comment: That is not in your question doing the off-topic since it is not reproducible.

Comment: I agree though. It would be nice if you edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `insertItem()` method and specify the location of the item:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QComboBox, QGridLayout


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        comboBox = QComboBox()
        comboBox.addItem('first item')
        comboBox.insertItem(1, 'second item')
        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(comboBox)
        self.setLayout(lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to add multiple items at once, you can simply use:

```
comboBox.addItems(['first item', 'second item'])
```

Check out the [QComboBox documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) for more info.

Comment: `combo.addItem(text)` is equivalent to `combo.insertItem(text, combo.coun())` so I think it is not the solution, See the source code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox.h.html#_ZN9QComboBox7addItemERK7QStringRK8QVariant . Have you been able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I wasn't aware they are equivalent. I thought `addItem` doesn't allow to specify the location? In any case, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce then it is difficult to help the OP so in those cases it is better to ask them to provide an MRE. I recommend you read [answer]

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! I simply assumed that OP's code (whatever it may look like) produced the problem which they claim it does. Given the little context they provided, I cannot reproduce the problem. I should have checked that.

Comment: This helps me identifying the real problem. It was when i set the index to ```-1``` and calls the ```comboBox.clear()``` and comboBox.addItem("dummy") it resets the index and set it to 0 which points to the newly added item.

Comment: Glad it helped! Good on you for figuring it out!